# Got a NumberFormatException while trying to parse a text file for objects

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

While trying to create objects and add them to an ArrayList using data from a text file, the program threw a NumberFormatException and I have absolutely no clue why, everything seemed OK to me. Here's the method in which the exception occurred:

```
static void read(String file) {
    anime.clear();

    try {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file); 
        while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] vals = fin.nextLine().split("[ ]");
            anime.add(new Anime(Integer.parseInt(vals[0]), 
                                vals[1], 
                                Integer.parseInt(vals[2]), 
                                Integer.parseInt(vals[3])));
        }
        fin.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Something went wrong!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }       
}
```

and here's the text file:

```
0 Angel_Beats! 13 2010
0 Baccano! 13 2007
0 Bakemonogatari 15 2009
0 Berserk 25 1997
0 Clannad 23 2007
```

Comment: try trim() on your vals[]. Maybe there are still white spaces?

Comment: Have you tried printing `Arrays.toString(vals)`?

Comment: Print your exception. Also, in addtion to printing the stack trace, print the value of each element of vals.

Comment: Maybe there's a blank line at the end of the file that's being read after the other lines have been processed, and you're trying to call `parseInt` on an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);` to `Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(file));` and it works perfectly now. I didn't think the difference mattered but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your `split()` call. Try just `split(" ")` without the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException invoke when you ll try to convert inavlid String for `eg:"abc"` value to integer..

this is 
valid string is `eg"123"`.
in your case split by space..

`split(" ");` will split line by `" "` by space..